# Okhttp sending http request after proxy connection is closed

Tags: java, proxy, okhttp

I'm tunneling my requests through a proxy that it seems like it closes the connection every 10-15 seconds. So if the client request a website and it takes some time the connection might be closed and therefore the okhttp library throws a "unexpected end of stream". Even though the connection is closed and the library throws that exception, the request has been successfully received by the server but the client couldn't check the answer. If I try to request the same url without proxy I have no problem and I receive the answer successfully.
Here you can see it wireshark:
[wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn1iB.png)

In the photo you can see at the end a request made by the client at 19:27:54,980 and then after 10 seconds, the client receives the FIN tcp packet. So after that Okhttp throws this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{m.apuestas.codere.es:443, proxy=HTTP @ /185.163.232.127:58542 hostAddress=/185.163.232.127:58542 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA protocol=http/1.1}
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:208)
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at com.telecobets.http.HTTPClient$LoggingInterceptor.intercept(HTTPClient.java:219)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at com.telecobets.http.HTTPClient$AddHeadersInterceptor.intercept(HTTPClient.java:199)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:188)
at com.main(Main.java:375)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:237)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
... 26 more
```

It is not the server who closes the connection because I've been doing different requests simultaneously to different servers and suddenly at the same time the connections got closed.
So my question is, is there a way to receive that answer even if the connection was closed by the proxy server?

Whole wireshark capture is [here](https://mega.nz/#!plIyDS5Y!Q8dZ8MBgy8Q1BDh4UFexKTWtPKsOvDYAzKIdkUOLf_s)

Proxy IP: 185.163.232.127:58542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy server provider was disconnecting connections every 10 seconds.